# How to get the last data of group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

How can I get the last row of employee_id of each departement_id in mysql?

I have two tables, departements and employees.

departements:

```
+----------------+------------------+------------+  
| departement_id | departement_name | manager_id |  
+----------------+------------------+------------+  
|             10 | Administration   |        101 |  
|             20 | IT               |        103 |  
+----------------+------------------+------------+
```

employees:

```
+-------------+--------+--------+------------+----------------+  
| employee_id | name   | salary | manager_id | departement_id |  
+-------------+--------+--------+------------+----------------+  
|         100 | Steven |   8000 |        101 |             10 |  
|         101 | Lexa   |  10000 |        101 |             10 |  
|         102 | Bruce  |   9000 |        103 |             20 |  
|         103 | Diana  |  11000 |        103 |             20 |  
|         104 | Bruce  |   8500 |        103 |             20 |  
+-------------+--------+--------+------------+----------------+
```

when I do this query:

```sql
select employee_id,name,employees.departement_id,avg(salary) from employees inner join departements on employees.departement_id=departements.departement_id group by employees.departement_id;
```

I get this result:

```
+-------------+--------+----------------+-------------+  
| employee_id | name   | departement_id | avg(salary) |  
+-------------+--------+----------------+-------------+  
|         100 | Steven |             10 |   9000.0000 |  
|         102 | Bruce  |             20 |   9500.0000 |  
+-------------+--------+----------------+-------------+
```

Please help me how to get this result:

```
+-------------+--------+----------------+-------------+  
| employee_id | name   | departement_id | avg(salary) |  
+-------------+--------+----------------+-------------+  
|         101 | Lexa   |             10 |   9000.0000 |  
|         104 | Bruce  |             20 |   9500.0000 |  
+-------------+--------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What determines which row is "last"?

Comment: @ysth the last row employee_id of each departement_id

Comment: **Problem 1**: The concepts of "first" or "last" relies on an ordering system. SQL tables are "unordered sets" and you cannot assume that the order you think that the data is stored in, will be the way it is processed. **Problem 2**: when using the **non-standard** group by feature of mysql, mysql can output ANY value for those columns not specified in the group by clause - but which don't have an aggregate function.

Comment: There is no concept of first or last rows; you need to decide how you want to order based on the stored data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query is permitted by MySQL because ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is OFF. You might not have made that choice or be aware that there is a choice. Before MySQL 5.7 it was OFF (either by default or because the option didn't exist) but from 5.7 the option is ON by default, and hence, since 5.7 by it became a choice. I would recommend you turn it back on and live with the restrictions it imposes.

When using non-standard group by queries (allowed when ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is OFF) there are 3 categories of columns:

1. Grouping columns i.e. those columns specified in the group by clause
2. "Aggregating" columns i.e. those using SUM/AVG/MIN/MAX/COUNT etc
3. "Non-Aggregating & Non-Grouping" columns i.e. any column not in 1 or 2

This third category of column **IS A BIG PROBLEM** and unless a whole range of special conditions exist what MySQL spits out into these columns is "non-deterministic" (i.e. pretty much random) and not even using an order by column improves this. Read from MySQL's own documentation:

> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard
> SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or
> ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns
> are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns.
>
> ... **In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each
> group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are
> nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want.**
>
> **Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.**

From: [12.19.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

```
CREATE TABLE departements (
    departement_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    departement_name VARCHAR(255),
    manager_id INT
);

 
CREATE TABLE employees (
    employee_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    salary INT,
    manager_id INT,
    departement_id INT
);

 
INSERT INTO departements (departement_id, departement_name, manager_id)
VALUES
(10, 'Administration', 101),
(20, 'IT', 103);


INSERT INTO employees (employee_id, name, salary, manager_id, departement_id)
VALUES
(100, 'Steven', 8000, 101, 10),
(101, 'Lexa', 10000, 101, 10),
(102, 'Bruce', 9000, 100, 20),
(103, 'Diana', 11000, 103, 20),
(104, 'Bruce', 8500, 103, 20);
```

---

```
-- force to OFF
SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));


SELECT
      employee_id               -- "non-aggregating" column
    , name                      -- "non-aggregating" column
    , employees.departement_id  -- grouped by
    , avg(salary)               -- aggregating column
FROM employees
INNER JOIN departements ON employees.departement_id = departements.departement_id
GROUP BY
     employees.departement_id
ORDER BY
      employee_id               -- "non-aggregating" column  
  ;
```

| employee_id | name | departement_id | avg(salary) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Steven | 10 | 9000.0000 |
| 102 | Bruce | 20 | 9500.0000 |

```
SELECT
      employee_id               -- "non-aggregating" column
    , name                      -- "non-aggregating" column
    , employees.departement_id  -- grouped by
    , avg(salary)               -- aggregating column
FROM employees
INNER JOIN departements ON employees.departement_id = departements.departement_id
GROUP BY
     employees.departement_id
ORDER BY
      employee_id  DESC        -- "non-aggregating" column  
  ;
```

| employee_id | name | departement_id | avg(salary) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | Bruce | 20 | 9500.0000 |
| 100 | Steven nb: expected 101, 'Lexa' i.e. order by did NOT work | 10 | 9000.0000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hKz32BWk)

Comment: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY was introduced in MySQL 4 (though not as a default for a long time after that)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of this: "*The default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 includes these modes: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY*..." have amended first paragraph a tad